# How to remove some option from the iOS Native Sharing abilities?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am working on a game for iOS and would like to know how remove some of the native options iOS offers when sharing automatically, such as "assign to contact" & "print". I have done a lot of research on this, the closest I could find is a suggestion to look into the UIActivityViewController but I haven't been able to find my solution, I am attaching two images, one of how it looks now and 2 how it needs to be at the end with the options removed, thanks!!!

[Link of how it looks now](http://oi39.tinypic.com/15s0qdy.jpg)

[Link with options removed](http://oi43.tinypic.com/33v0yeu.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `excludedActivityTypes` property of `UIActivityViewController`.

```
NSArray *items = ... // your activity items
UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
activityView.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint ];
activityView.completionHandler = ... // your completion block
// display activity view here
```

Comment: can you remove whatsApp, viber also ? i don't think so